# showing a DatePickerDialog inside a Dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I created a `DialogFragment`that has an `EditText`, and when the user presses the `EditText` there is a new `DatePickerDialog` that suppose to pick a date from the user and then set it in the `DialogFragment`. I am having a hard time to do so:

1. The DatePickerDialog actually shows up but destroys the old `DialogFragment`. When I click ok/whatever I return to the activity.
2. I want to pass the date that I picked back to the fragment. It was easier if I wanted to pass it back to an activity because I can use `getActivity()` method. So how can I pass the date I picked back to the fragment that called the picker?

**Main Fragment**

```
public class NewWorkoutItemFragment extends android.app.DialogFragment implements
    View.OnClickListener {

private String mDate;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_workout_item, container, false);

    //A lot of code

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.NewWorkout_date_et:
        //Call to DatePickerDialog
        DialogFragment pickDate = new DatePickerFragment();
        pickDate.show(getFragmentManager(), "show");
}

public void setmDate(String mDate) {
    this.mDate = mDate;
}
}
```

**DatePickerFragment**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends android.app.DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker.
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it.
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
String dateString = Integer.toString(dayOfMonth) +
                "/" + Integer.toString(month+1) +
                "/" + Integer.toString(year);
    //note- Return dateString back to NewWorkoutItemFragment, using setmDate
}
}
```

Comment: you should use `'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'` library for `datepicker` or `timepicker` dialogs.

Comment: @Raza I'm going to try it and will update the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution isn't about the `datepickerdialog` at all. I had a switch-case in my fragment that manages the events of clicks. I accidentally forgot to put a `break;` after the case which caused a flow to the other events (one of them was `dismiss();`), and that's why the datepickerdialog also dismissed my fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'` library for `datepicker` or `timepicker` dialogs.
First of all add the dependency in `app level gradle file`. After that create a new java file with `NewWorkoutItemFragment extends DialogFragment`.

```
public class NewWorkoutItemFragment extends DialogFragment implements 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@OnClick(R.id.layout_time)
public void onClickTime(View view){
    calendar= Calendar.getInstance();


        datePickerDialog= TimePickerDialog.newInstance(NewWorkoutItemFragment.this,
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), // Initial year selection
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), // Initial month selection
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) // Inital day selection
                false);

    datePickerDialog.setThemeDark(false);
    datePickerDialog.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#58a5f0"));
    datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
    datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"DatePicker Dialog");

}

public NewWorkoutItemFragment() {
}

public static NewWorkoutItemFragment newInstance (String title) {
    NewWorkoutItemFragment frag = new NewWorkoutItemFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(final Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    final Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams windowLayoutParams = window.getAttributes();
        windowLayoutParams.dimAmount = DIM_AMOUNT;
    }
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    return dialog;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
                         final ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dlg_network, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final int width = getScreenWidth();
    changeWindowSizes(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}

private void changeWindowSizes(int width, int height) {
    final Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        // hack to change window width
        window.setLayout(width, height);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mUnbinder.unbind();
}

@Override
public int getTheme() {
    return R.style.CustomDialog;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
 String date = "You picked the following date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year;
 dateTextView.setText(date);
}


}
```

and the class where you want to open `NewWorkoutItemFragment`just make the object of this dialog class  like

```
newWorkDialog= new NewWorkoutItemFragment();
NewWorkoutItemFragment newWorkDialog;
newWorkDialog= NewWorkoutItemFragment.newInstance("T");
newWorkDialog.show(manager,"Show");
```

in styles file just add the following lines

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomDialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/translate_left_side</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/translate_right_side</item>
</style>
```

And create a new package inside `res` and name it `anim` and create two files in `anim` folder `transition_left_side` and `transition_right_side`.

Code for `transition_left_side`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="600"
android:fromXDelta="100%"
android:toXDelta="0%"/>
```

and code for `transition_right_side`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
android:duration="600"/>
```

I guess this will not create any further errors.

Comment: I'm having too many errors with this code, i.e `mUnbinder` is on "cannot resolve this.."

Comment: these are the variables which i have to use , you can globally declare these variables or just comment those. and write your own variables.

Comment: private Unbinder mUnbinder; this is the global variable which is initialized inside onCreateView as mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

Comment: I appreciate your kindness but I managed to solve my problems, and it had nothing to do with my `DatePickerDialog`. it was a silly one. I'll post a solution. p.s: I do now use 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0' library datepicker, just because I like the themes. Thank you