# DatePickerObject.setMinDate() is not working within OnDataChanged() in android in second or third times

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-date, android-dateutils

In `DatePicker`, on `DataChanged` callback when I select weekends either saturday or sunday,I am programatically changing the date to upcoming monday/tuesday using `view.setMinDate(expectedDay)`. During initial press 2 or 3 times, it works correctly. By Pressing 3 times consecutively or clicking any days randomly to and forth in datepicker the same day(saturday/sunday) is getting selected which should not happen, it should go to programmatically changed date. By Logic it goes to expected if case, `view.setMinDate()` is called again, it is in same day instead of navigating to expected day programmatically.

```
 tvStartDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {



            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialogFromDate = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), R.style.datePickerTheme, fromDateListner, fromDateCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    fromDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(@NonNull DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    //super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, dayOfMonth);
                    // Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    testCalendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                    Date choosenDate = testCalendar.getTime();
                    String dayOfTheWeek = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(choosenDate);
                    Log.v("Selected Day of Week >>>>", dayOfTheWeek);
                    try {
                        if (dayOfTheWeek.equalsIgnoreCase("THURSDAY")) {
                            Log.v("Day of Week >>>>THURSDAY", "Should be Monday");
                            view.setMinDate(testCalendar.getTimeInMillis() + 4 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        } else if (dayOfTheWeek.equalsIgnoreCase("FRIDAY")) {
                            Log.v("Day of Week >>>>FRIDAY", "Should be Tuesday");
                            view.setMinDate(testCalendar.getTimeInMillis() + 4 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        } else if (dayOfTheWeek.equalsIgnoreCase("SATURDAY")) {
                            Log.v("Day of Week >>>>SATURDAY", "Should be Tuesday");
                            view.setMinDate(testCalendar.getTimeInMillis() + 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        } else if (dayOfTheWeek.equalsIgnoreCase("SUNDAY")) {
                            Log.v("Day of Week >>>>SUNDAY", "Should be Tuesday");
                            view.setMinDate(testCalendar.getTimeInMillis() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        } else {
                            view.setMinDate(testCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
                        }
                        view.invalidate();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.v("Exception in getting Day of Week>>", ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };
            datePickerDialogFromDate.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + Integer.parseInt(mReservationIntvl) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            datePickerDialogFromDate.show();

    });
```

Is it this my code issue or any there workaround for it?I tried to get date from datepicker using datepicker.getMin()

```
    public void updateDaysInDatePickerView(final DatePicker datePickerView, int noOfDays, Date date) {
    try {
        long NO_OF_DAYS_IN_MILLISECS = noOfDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        long pushed_date = NO_OF_DAYS_IN_MILLISECS + date.getTime();
        datePickerView.setMinDate(pushed_date);

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                datePickerView.invalidate();
                Calendar takenCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                takenCalendar.setTimeInMillis(datePickerView.getMinDate());
                Log.v("Day is>>>", "" + takenCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
                Log.v("Month is>>>", "" + takenCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                Log.v("Year is>>>", "" + takenCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception is this updateDaysInDatePickerView>>>", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Date is showing as Monday not in UI is not getting updated,i tried invalidating view,it is not updating.

I tried in redmi note 5 pro(8.0),it is working as expected,In Samsung S6 edge,and A2Max,(7.1 & 7.1.1)we are getting this issue,I am not sure this issue is device as specific or OS specific not sure.

Comment: Can you post the code, you've tried

Comment: you should use 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0' library for datepicker or timepicker dialogs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815653/10340976 you could find some help here

Comment: have a look at it. https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Date-Picker-Example-/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/muhammadatif/datepicker/dateexample/dialogfragment/DateTimeDialog.java